# How to start and shutdown an OSGi container properly?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, bnd

I have made a bundle which has an Activator file that basically launches other bundles by their correct order. I needed this because the framework would start some bundles before their dependencies have finished starting. For example my bundles depending on my log service would start before it, so log messages would not be stored for those bundles. With this Activator I can choose who starts first, since there is no clear way to do it in **felix**.

The code for this is here:

```
package lumina.launcher;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;

public final class Launcher implements BundleActivator {

    private BundleContext context;

    private final String relativePath = "./bundle/";

    private final void print(String msg) {
        // System.out.println(msg);
    }

    private Bundle install(String path) throws BundleException {
        Bundle bundle = this.context.installBundle("file:/" + path);
        print("\tInstalling: " + bundle.getSymbolicName());
        return bundle;
    }

    private boolean isJar(String fileName) {
        final String[] tokens = fileName.split("\\.");
        return tokens.length != 0 && "jar".equals(tokens[tokens.length - 1]);
    }

    private String[] listFilesForFolder(final File folder)
            throws BundleException {
        final List<String> bundles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                if (isJar(fileEntry.getName())) {
                    bundles.add(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath().replace(
                            File.separatorChar, '/'));
                }
            }
        }
        return bundles.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        this.context = context;
        installStart("third-party");
        installStart("shared-components");
        installStart("lumina");
        installStart("webconsole");
        System.out
                .println("-> You can access Felix WebConsole at http://localhost:8080/system/console");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        installStart("plugins");
    }

    private final void installStart(String path) throws BundleException {
        print("Installing " + path);
        final String[] targetBundles = listFilesForFolder(new File(relativePath
                + path));
        final Bundle[] bundles = new Bundle[targetBundles.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < targetBundles.length; i++) {
            bundles[i] = install(targetBundles[i]);
        }
        print("\tStarting installed bundles...");
        for (Bundle b : bundles)
            b.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

And this is how I organized my bundles in felix's bundle/ folder.

```
C:\felix\BUNDLE
│   .gitignore
│   lumina.launcher-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│
├───lumina
│       .gitignore
│       lumina.api-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
│
├───plugins
│       .gitignore
│       lumina.assembler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       lumina.extensions.drivers.ip-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       lumina.rest-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       shared.extensions.base.logger-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       smartcampuskndriver.gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       smartcampusmetersip.gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│
├───shared-components
│       codebase-2.0.0.jar
│       shared.osgi.services-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       shared.osgi.services.logger-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       shared.properties.api-5.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
│
├───third-party
│       com.googlecode.json-simple_1.1.0.jar
│       org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-2.0.2.jar
│       org.apache.servicemix.bundles.joda-time-2.3_1.jar
│       org.apache.servicemix.bundles.junit-4.11_1.jar
│       org.osgi.compendium-1.4.0.jar
│       org.osgi.core-1.4.0.jar
│       org.restlet.ext.json_2.1.0.M1.jar
│       org.restlet.jse.org.restlet.lib.org.json_2.0.0.jar
│       org.restlet_2.1.0.M1.jar
│       OSGiJMX.jar
│
├───unused
│       org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.14.0.jar
│       org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.12.1.jar
│       org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar
│
└───webconsole
        org.apache.felix.http.api-2.3.2.jar
        org.apache.felix.http.jetty-2.3.2.jar
        org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api-1.0.1.jar
        org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.2.4-all.jar
```

Note that **lumina.launcher-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar** is where my Activator is and is the only bundle auto-started by felix.

This works fine by the way, dunno if there is a smarter way to do this. So the idea of the above code is to start all bundles from each directory by the following order: third-party, shared-components, lumina, webconsole and plugins.

On the other hand, when I hit ^C in the terminal while the OSGi container is running, it begins stopping all bundles one by one. This is ok, but the log service is one of the first bundles to stop, and I want it to be one of the last bundles. Is there a way to set the order by which bundles are stopped when the OSGi container is closing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I needed this because the framework would start some bundles before their dependencies have finished starting.

One of the rules of OSGi is that all bundles should be implemented in the way that starting order does not matter.

In case you really need starting order, you should set start levels for your bundles. See chapter 10.5 of OSGi core specification to get more information about start levels.

Comment: I have to set an order, and I think it is unreal not setting a startup order. In my situation, I have a log service registry in a bundle (A), then I have some logger implementations in another bundle (B), then I have one bundle which logs stuff (C).

One thing OSGi will never do is start B before starting A. However it can start C before starting B. So C will start logging stuff before I have any logger implementations installed.

Comment: In my situation OSGi is launching bundles in the order A,C and B, and all I wanted was making it launch like A,B and C. The same goes for shutting down, the correct order for stopping bundles would be C,B and A.

How can I define start levels in Felix Framework?

Comment: You can configure felix to start bundles with a specific startlevel. See the description of configuration setting felix.auto.start.<n> at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html. Also, see the description of other configuration options where startlevel is mentioned.

Comment: If you use e.g. declarative services (e.g. by using the the Apache Felix SCR annotations), then you can declare the logging service as required for services in C. The framework will then make sure the services get started in the correct order.

Comment: Yes. That is the most common way to make bundles start-order independent if the starting order would matter due to service starts. There is a good article about starting order issues at http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Avoid_Start_Order_Dependencies